# How to allow a user to publish items one by one, but not the entire site

Tags: security, content-management, role-management

I received a client request where they want me to modify the Author role; so that any user with this role can view and modify a subset of items, and can publish only a single item at a time and not the entire site, is there a role or group that would provide such access?

Comment: You can try removing access rights from the `publish site` buttons

Comment: What happens if they select the root sitecore item and do a publish with subitems.  Just a suggestion that maybe you should also cover this case.

Comment: @Muradious maybe you can use workflow instead of direct publishing and disable the whole Pblish button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Marek for leading me in the right way, there is a great blog post about hiding the Publish Site buttons written by Marek himself, basically what needs to be done is the following

> In order to hide them, you need to switch the database to Core, run the Security Editor application, select the role and:
>   remove the Read permission from the sitecore > content > document and settings > all users > start menu > left > publish site item,
>   deny the Read permission from the sitecore > content > applications > content editor > menues > publish site item.

Answer (score 3):

Try to make your "Author" role a member of "Sitecore Client Publishing" role to view and modify a subset of items, and can publish only a single item.

Answer (score 1):

## Sitecore PowerShell Extensions

You could consider using something like the [Multi-Item Publish with SPE](http://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2015/12/14/Multi-Item-Publish-with-Sitecore-Powershell-Extensions/). Richard Seal did a nice job building a module as an addon to Sitecore PowerShell Extensions.

You essentially get a convenient UI to select items and publish.
[image: Picture taken from the article]

The script and script library is aware of the rules engine, therefore allowing you to specify security for your custom group.

#### Docs

See more documentation in the [book](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/content-editor.html).